# Using JSON.NET to populate a list of sports events

Tags: arrays, json, list, documentation, json.net

Newbie here.

I've got a C# Windows Presentation Forms program and I'm trying to add a method that downloads the string of a JSON webpage and then creates a list of events (each of which has a list of teams attending) from the data in the page. The only problem is that the JSON.NET documentation is confusing me and I can't seem to get a grasp on JSON format in general.

For reference, there are *two* parts to this method:
**1)** get the list of "official" events (if you look you will notice there is an "official" boolean value in each event item) and create a string list containing each event "key" (the first value in each event item)
**2)** for each event "key", make a list of teams attending each event and sort each team by their "team_number"

*[Here is a test page for the event list.](http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/events/2014?X-TBA-App-Id=frc3593:scouticus:v01.0test) [Here is the test page for the team list from one event.](http://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v2/event/2014abca/teams?X-TBA-App-Id=frc3593:scouticus:v01.0test)*

My biggest problem with the JSON.NET library/documentation is that I can't seem to figure out how to take each item and isolate one specific value from it. For example, there are a whole bunch of values in each event item, but I only need the "official" value and the "key" value. Same with the teams, I only need the "team_number" value from each item.

Can you guys help me understand the library a little bit more or maybe even point me to the correct library if this is the wrong one for the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com) to generate the classes that represent your JSON.

```
public class Event
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string website { get; set; }
    public bool official { get; set; }
    public string end_date { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string facebook_eid { get; set; }
    public string event_district_string { get; set; }
    public string venue_address { get; set; }
    public int? event_district { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string event_code { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
    public List<object> webcast { get; set; }
    public List<object> alliances { get; set; }
    public string event_type_string { get; set; }
    public string start_date { get; set; }
    public int event_type { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public string website { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    public int rookie_year { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    public int team_number { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public string nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize the JSON into lists of those objects and use LINQ to query what you need out of the list. I'm doing this from memory so it may need some tweaking to work.

```
var events = JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<Event>>( eventJson );
var officialEvents = events.Where( e => e.official )
    .Select( e => new { e.key, e.official } );
```